# Jquery prependTo but after

Tags: jquery

I need to prepend h1 to `#columns` but after `#left_column`, now it is before it. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(init);
    function init() {
        $('h1').prependTo('#columns');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.appendTo('#left_column')` is the obvious suggestion, but will append before the column is closed (cheers Rory, in comments).

If you want it to go after the column, use `.after('#left_column')`.

Comment: This is incorrect - it will place the `h1` inside the `#left_column` element, not after it.

Comment: Like this $('h1').appendTo('#left_column').after('#left_column'); ?

Comment: Ok, it is working, here is the result - $('h1').insertAfter('#left_column');